# How old is grandma in My Big Fat Greek Wedding 2?

Tags: character, big-fat-greek-wedding-2

The Grandma, played by Bess Meisler in *My Big Fat Greek Wedding 2* is lovable comic relief for the movie. But when the neighbours in movie were wondering how old the Grandma is, it got me wondering too.

So, how old is Grandma in universe?

Comment: Bess Meidler was born in 1949 and she recently died on July 6, 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the IMDB [page](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjl5OLlqp3MAhUJnoMKHaG2DDoQFggkMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftitle%2Ftt3760922%2F&usg=AFQjCNEgIbvZD2jlWgj5uu-OxPe5TvWnjQ&sig2=fHwhnTgtmC_dDnQAR2WHZQ), it notes that she is "believed to be in her 90s".  I'm fairly certain the age isn't confirmed at any point in the movie.

Answer (score 1):

During the commentary during the movie My Big Fat Greek Wedding they say she's 60. So now, 2016, she's 74...